# Postgres indexing on whether column is null or not

Tags: postgresql

I have a table like..

```
CREATE TABLE msgs_msg (
  id serial primary key,
  ...
  visibility char(1), -- 'V' or 'A'
  flow_id integer NULL REFERENCES flows_flow(id) -- 100s of different possible values
)
```

And I'm trying to figure out the best way to index for 3 different ordered views of that table (i.e. getting pages of 25, ordered by `id DESC`)

1. `visibility = 'V' AND flow_id IS NULL`
2. `visibility = 'V' AND flow_id IS NOT NULL`
3. `visibility = 'A'`

Option 1 is just make 3 perfect partial indexes, but this table already has quite a few indexes, and I keep reading that that [lots of partial indexes is bad idea](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-partial.html).

Option 2 is a single index on `(visibility, flow_id, id DESC)` but I'm only interested in whether `flow_id` is null or not, so surely that makes for inefficient index reading?

Option 3 I thought was an index on `(visibility, (flow_id IS NULL), id DESC)` which works fine for querying on `visibility = 'V' AND flow_id IS NULL`.. but doesn't seem to work for `visibility = 'V' AND flow_id IS NOT NULL` no matter how I tweak the query, e.g. `visibility = 'V' AND (flow_id IS NULL) = FALSE`

Option 4 a single index on a more complicated expression? Maybe `CASE WHEN flow_id IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 THEN` but I'm not even sure how to query on that.

Comment: The answer will depend on 1) how nany percent of the rows have which `visibility` 2) how many percent of the rows have `flow_id IS NULL` 3) how will the queries using the views look like?

Comment: `visibility = 'V'` is about 99%, `flow_id IS NULL` about 20%. Queries would look something like.. `SELECT * FROM msgs_msg WHERE visibility = 'V' AND flow_id IS NULL ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 25`

Comment: A lot of partial indexes is a bad idea, but 3 is not a lot.  If you have a lot of other indexes, maybe you can drop some of them.  Surely not something we can advice on given the lack of info.  You shouldn't compensate for having too many indexes of one kind by having too few of another kind.

Answer (score 1):

There is no point in indexing `visibility = 'V'` or `flow_id IS NOT NULL`.

If your other query criteria are selective (they filter out almost all rows), you don't need an additional index.

If your filter criteria are *not* selective and you have `ORDER BY id` and `LIMIT`, then an index on `id` is enough.

For the other cases, I would go with two partial indexes:

```
CREATE INDEX ON msgs_msg (id) WHERE flow_id IS NULL;
CREATE INDEX ON msgs_msg (id) WHERE visibility = 'A';
```

These indexes are comparatively small, they support `ORDER BY id` and they can be combined with other indexes.